# How to prevent a div's content to start a new line

Tags: html, css

I've a div with a width of 450px. What I want to do is, whenever the div's max width has achieved, it won't start a new line.

for instance, if I have this code:

```
<div style="width:450px">this is my content</div>
```

I want the output to be:

`this is my content` and if I will decide to make the div now 60px, the output will be:

`this i` which means the rest of the word has gotten cut and not a new line like this:

```
this
is my
content
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: use `nowrap` property

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `overflow: hidden` and `white-space: nowrap` in your div style.

```
<div id="divId">this is my content</div>
```

And in css part

```
# divId {
    width:450px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Check out this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jnKs8/3/)

Comment: I have one query with C#

Answer (score 0):

Use word-wrap:break-word

```
<div id="divId">this is my content</div>

# divId {
width:450px;
word-wrap:break-word;
}
```